# Erro no node-sass ao tentar instalar as dependencias de um projeto feito com ionic 3

Tags: node.js, ionic, ionic3, npm, sass

Olá tenho um projeto feito no ionic 3.2.0, o projeto em questão pode ser encontrado no seguinte link https://github.com/Mathe13/rodoviasApp, realizei o download pelo git, removia o node_module e dei o comando npm i para realizar o download dos pacotes e tive o seguinte erro:

```html
/home/matheus/.node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3002:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
binding.target.mk:127: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/matheus/Documentos/ionic/rodoviasApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/matheus/Documentos/ionic/rodoviasApp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/matheus/Documentos/ionic/rodoviasApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/matheus/Documentos/ionic/rodoviasApp/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/matheus/.npm/_logs/2019-07-25T00_57_44_503Z-debug.log
```

ao olhar o arquivo de log achei a seguinte mensagem:

```html
Error: node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
```

Meu sistema operacional é Debian 9.9 stretch

A saída do 'node -v' é v12.7.0

Alguém sabe como resolver?Se precisar de mais dados eu atualizo a questão

Comment: Tente um "npm rebuild node-sass".

Comment: dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Use a versão 10.16.0 do NodeJS. A 12.7.0 é muito recente e não recomendada para todos os projetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo [essas orientações](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906314/5203904), pra mim funcionou:

- Exclua o `package-lock.json`
- Exclua a pasta `node_modules`
- Rode `npm install` novamente